# BH Curve of ST52.0 - S355J0

Tags: electrical-engineering, electromagnetism

I need to BH curve of ST52.0. Could anyone help to me?

Comment: Start with the data sheets.

Comment: Duplicate https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/49556/10902

Comment: I cant find data sheet of st52. You may share with me?